# using .replace to replace more than one character in python

Tags: python, string, replace

so I am trying to make a simple program that will decode one phrase into a different one.

This is the code I have now

```
def mRNA_decode(phrase):
    newphrase = phrase.replace('A','U'),phrase.replace('T','A'),phrase.replace('C','G'),phrase.replace('G','C')
    return newphrase
```

So basically, if I give the string `'TATCGTTAATTCGAT'`, the desired output would be `'AUAGCAAUUAAGCUA'`

instead, I get `('TUTCGTTUUTTCGUT', 'AAACGAAAAAACGAA', 'TATGGTTAATTGGAT', 'TATCCTTAATTCCAT')`, which is the phrase I entered but instead of adding the changes all into one phrase, it prints four different translations all with only one character being changes in each translation.

How would I change the code so the newphrase is translated so it is on consecutive string with the desired output instead of having four different phrases?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You need translate instead of replace

Comment: Replacing C to G and G to C is wrong. Result will be only Cs, which is not you expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's because you are replacing every time with your `phrase` variable , the value of `phrase` doesn't change , so you have 4 different outputs

an advice , using translate function instead :

```
from string import maketrans
intab = "ATCG"
outtab = "UAGC"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)
phrase.translate(trantab)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.translate()` with a *translate table*:

```
s = 'TATCGTTAATTCGAT'

s.translate(str.maketrans("ATCG", "UAGC"))
# 'AUAGCAAUUAAGCUA'
```

Comment: i learned sth new , thank you !

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i tested it on python 3 , it works

Comment: my bad! I thought it did not work anymore. Sorry for that! And that's the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

So as an fyi, remember the order is important. For example, if you need to swap characters `c` and `a` in the string `cat`, you can't replace `c` with `a` then `a` with `c`. Otherwise you'd get these steps:

`cat` --> `aat` --> `cct`

Comment: doesn't really answers, but helps fixing other wrong answers seen here.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
def mRNA_decode(phrase):
    newphrase = phrase.replace('A','U').replace('T','A').replace('C','G').replace('G','C')
    return newphrase
```

Since str is immutable, `replace` returns new string all the time, and you just need to call next `replace` method on newly create string.

In your question, you make four independent operations on same string, so they produce four new string per each call. You listed them separated by comma, which is interpreted by Python as tuple declaration.

UPD: as mentioned in comments, instead of few `replace` call  you can call `phrase.translate()`. You can find an example in other answers.

Comment: using `str.translate()` would be more efficient, though

Comment: thank you for note. I will update the answer.

Comment: I don't get it: `replace('C','G').replace('G','C')` clearly doesn't work. It does nothing useful. Please fix or delete your answer. It is wrong.