# String replace() vs string translate() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question regarding my code below:

Input:  A DNA string Pattern (ex: `'AAAACCCGGT'`)

Output: The complementary string (ex: `'TTTTGGGCCA'`)

```
def Complement(Pattern):
    comPattern=Pattern.translate(str.maketrans({'A':'T','T':'A','G':'C','C':'G'}))
    return comPattern
```

I tried using `str.replace()` method multiple times for above problem, but it did not work. Any idea why?

Comment: We can't see what you did with `str.replace`, but probably the issue was that it doesn't apply all the changes in one go - once you've replaced all the As with Ts, for example, when you then replace all the Ts with As some of these Ts are your original As getting switched straight back again.

Comment: Actually they are two slightly different questions, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41838634) is a better answer for this question than for the other question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Above code works great but when I tried using the replace method this way: Pattern.replace('A','T').replace('C','G').replace('T','A').replace('G','C'), it did not give me the desired output. I understand now from your explanation. Thank you.